# How to block a port on localhost?

Tags: networking, windows-10, apache-http-server, localhost, tomcat

Here's my scenario: I have an Apache load balancer in front of two Tomcats (this is on Windows). Periodically I'd like to ensure that traffic gets routed to a specific Tomcat. Stopping one Tomcat is not an option because bringing it up takes a few seconds. Pausing it is also not good because I've noticed that paused processes frequently behave strangely when they come back online. What I thought of doing is blocking the port between Apache and one Tomcat. I'm not sure that's feasible since I read that blocking a port on localhost is impossible. Is that true? Are there other options to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Are the load balancer and the Tomcat servers on different machines or are you trying to block traffic within a single box?

Comment: Why not just define a specific instance as a target in your LB configuration?

Comment: Disable the unwanted node in the Apache config and then apply it using "gracefully reload" in Apache.

Answer (score 0):

To block a port on Windows localhost you go on to the Windows Firewall, click the Advanced Settings on the left panel. When the screen 'Windows Firewall with Advanced Security' opens, click 'InBound Rules', then 'Action' / 'New Rule...' Select 'Port' and click 'Next', then select options for port: TCP/UDP and port number, click 'Next'. Then finally you can select 'Block the connection'.

But I have to say that the best option to accomplish what you have described it to change de Apache configuration and just to 'reload' it.